# How can I implement navigation in MVVM?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, portable-class-library

I've just completed a very basic MVVM example by using the [Portable Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh563947.aspx). But how do I do navigation? I want it to be portable, as I'm going to make a Windows app and a Windows Phone app. Do I have to use a library, if then which and ifnot how?

I would really love not to depend on another library as this is a very simple Application.

Answer (score 2):

There's already an example in the Windows Dev Center: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-CodeAdding-a4c4beb8

> This sample has the goal to show an example about NavigationService in share code scenarios, that will be registered in one Ioc container and injected by view model's contructor. The idea is to have an INavigationService interface that is portable and used in portable view models, in pratice will have diferent implementation in the platform project.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Navigation itself is typically of scope for the MVVM approach because of platform differences. Windows Store and Windows Phone applications have a different navigation stack, that you have to adapt to individually.